# Error handling on GoTo Bookmark if bookmark doesn't exist

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a macro to copy and paste bookmarked tables from one word document to another. It works fine as long as the value I put in the input box matches an existing bookmark, but if I mistype the value, it simply pulls in the top table from my source document. I understand why it does that (because it selects table 1 if it doesn't find a bookmark), but I can't figure out how to fix it. I tried putting in error handling, but since it doesn't trigger an error, what I added doesn't work. Can someone show me how to edit the code below to fix this issue? Also, is there a way to use relative pathways for the source document and target document? They will always be in the same folder, but each different user will have a copy of them in their own folder, and I don't want to rewrite the macro every time. Any other improvements or edits would be appreciated, such as how to not use the selection event so much here. Or how to not reopen the documents if they are already open. The command button (and code) is in the Target document (Product.docm)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

' Copy table from source document and add to table in target document

  Dim oTarDoc As Document, oSourceDoc As Document   
  Dim oTable As Table   
  Dim oNewRow As Row

    Set oSourceDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\Tables.docx")   
    Set oTarDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\Product.docm")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    oTarDoc.Activate
    Set oTable = oTarDoc.Tables(2)
    Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.Count - 3)

    oSourceDoc.Activate
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="A" & InputBox("119f, 979, 981a...", "Enter Number and Letter as Shown")
    With oSourceDoc.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
    Selection.Tables(1).Select
    Selection.Copy

    oTarDoc.Activate
    oNewRow.Select
    Selection.Paste
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't amend your code for adding the row as I had suggested. It was your own previous code which caused the error. The following code is tested and works as you now describe.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    ' Copy table from source document and add to table in target document

    Dim TarDoc As Document, SourDoc As Document
    Dim Tbl As Table
    Dim NewRow As Row
    Dim Mark As String, MarkText As String

    Set SourDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\Tables.docx")
    Set TarDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\Product.docm")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Tbl = TarDoc.Tables(2)
    With Tbl
       Set NewRow = .Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=.Rows(.Rows.Count - 2))
    End With

    Do
        Mark = InputBox("119f, 979, 981a...", "Enter Number and Letter as Shown")
        If Len(Mark) Then              ' do nothing if user enters nothing
            Mark = "A" & Mark
            If SourDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(Mark) Then
                MarkText = SourDoc.Bookmarks(Mark).Range.Text
                NewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = MarkText
                Mark = vbNullString    ' to enable existing the loop
            Else
                MsgBox "Bookmark """ & Mark & """ doesn't exist.", vbInformation, _
                       "Invalid entry"
            End If
        End If
    Loop While Len(Mark)               ' the user entered a wrong mark

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
Dim bm As Word.Bookmark
Dim bm_name As String
.
.
bm_name = "A" & InputBox("119f, 979, 981a...", "Enter Number and Letter as Shown")
' TODO: if user hits Cancel, bm_name = "", need to trap with If bm_name=""
On Error Resume Next
Set bm = oSourceDoc.Bookmarks(bm_name)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    bm.Select
    Selection.Tables(1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ' Paste-to-target code goes here

Else
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "Didn't find " bm_name, vbOKOnly, "Not found"
End If
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This seems to work, but now if I hit the command button, it pastes whatever I currently have on my clipboard into the new row. I need it to either exit the sub if the bookmark doesn't exist with an error message to inform the user, or pop up a new input box saying that's an invalid number, please try again, and automatically rerun that portion of the sub.

Comment: I edited the code to make it more complete. It pops ups a message box when the number is invalid. It doesn't do automatic retry, but you could modify the code for that. It also doesn't handle when the user hit's Cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. I have added some comments which I hope you will find useful.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    ' Copy table from source document and add to table in target document

    Dim TarDoc As Document, SourDoc As Document
    Dim Tbl As Table
    Dim NewRow As Row
    Dim Mark As String, MarkText As String

    Set SourDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\Tables.docx")
    Set TarDoc = Documents.Open("H:\Test Documents\Product.docm")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'    TarDoc.Activate                            ' no need to activate
    ' actually, since ScreenUpdating is off, Activate is without effect
    Set Tbl = TarDoc.Tables(2)
    Set NewRow = Tbl.Rows(Tbl.Rows.Count - 3)   ' this is an existing row
    ' this code inserts a row before the existing row(3)
    ' With Tbl
    '    .Rows.Add BeforeRow:=.Rows(3)
    ' End With
    ' use Tbl.Rows.Add to append a row at the end
'    SourDoc.Activate                           ' no need to activate

    Do
        Mark = InputBox("119f, 979, 981a...", "Enter Number and Letter as Shown")
        If Len(Mark) Then              ' do nothing if user enters nothing
            Mark = "A" & Mark
            If SourDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(Mark) Then
                MarkText = SourDoc.Bookmarks(Mark).Range.Text
                ' This seems to serve no purpose:
                '    With SourDoc.Bookmarks
                '        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
                '        .ShowHidden = False
                '    End With
                '    Selection.Tables(1).Select ' no need to select
                '    Selection.Copy             ' MarktText already got the text
                '    TarDoc.Activate            ' no need to activate
                '    NewRow.Select              ' no need to select
                '    Selection.Paste            ' no need to paste
                NewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = MarkText
                Mark = vbNullString    ' to enable existing the loop
            Else
                MsgBox "Bookmark """ & Mark & """ doesn't exist.", vbInformation, _
                       "Invalid entry"
            End If
        End If
    Loop While Len(Mark)               ' the user entered a wrong mark

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If the user enters a non-existing mark name he gets an error message and another chance. To exit the InputBox without entering a valid bookmark just leave it blank.

Comment: Ok, so I pasted this code into the command button. When I run the code, it deletes the information from the fourth row from the bottom (when I actually need a new row inserted at that point), and it leaves the row blank. I tried it with several bookmarks, and same thing. The target document has a table on it that I need to add to, but the bottom four rows of that table are final information (user name, notes, etc.) and have to stay at the bottom. I need to add rows to import the data from the source doc. I will usually add between 2-7 rows.

Comment: Is it easier to just grab the table from the source document (each table is just one row) corresponding to the bookmark and insert that row into the target document table at a point 4 rows up from the bottom? That would clear up any issues with adding new rows, then pasting text into those rows.